# Alfresco Maven Junit test

Tags: spring, maven, junit4, alfresco

I want to test some classes from a alfresco module (AMP) project.
The project is based to maven 3.

I'm quite new to Alfresco and Maven, so please be patient ... :)
The folder src/main/java includes all classes of  the module.
Now I've created a test class in src/test/java with the same package as the class I want to test.
The test class extends the BaseAlfrescoTestCase class.

I added JUnit 4.11 to the POM dependencies.

Executing `mvn clean integration-test -P webapp` I got an exception, that the application-context.xml was not found:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.189 sec <<< FAILURE!
>   testCreateinitialSpaces(AlfresoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.158 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [alfresco/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [alfresco/application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>       at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(BaseApplicationContextHelper.java:67)
>       at org.alfresco.util.ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextHelper.java:46)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUpContext(BaseAlfrescoTestCase.java:84)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUp(BaseAlfrescoTestCase.java:102)

Apparently the BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUp method is not able to get the injected properties (as serviceRegistry etc ...) from Spring Framework.

The application-context.xml actually doesn't exist, but unfortunately I have no clue how to set up a proper application-context.xml for test purpose.

I thought the application-context is provided by jetty?
The pom.xml was original configured by a colleague and he is not reachable right now.
Jetty starts properly when I am skipping the tests:
`mvn clean -Dmaven.test.skip=true integration-test -P webapp`

I searched a lot, but I did not find many tutorials for Alfresco in combination with Maven and Junit. All tutorials I've found did not work for me...
Thanks for your help

EDIT:
here are all dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.b</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <classifier>community</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.c</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-datamodel</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.c</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.c</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opensymphony.quartz</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.extensions.surf</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webscripts</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1b</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

EDIT:

```
after adding application-context.xml, application-context-core.xml and a fake-context folder to resource folder in the maven project this error occurs:

testCreateinitialSpaces(AlfrescoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.56 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ServiceRegistry' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
    at org.alfresco.util.BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUp(BaseAlfrescoTestCase.java:105)
```

Apparently the ServiceRegistry Bean is not available?!

EDIT:
I copied the complete Alfresco folder from `<WAR>/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco` to `src/test/resources`. Actually no XML file is missing anymore, but the test fails with CannotLoadBeanClassException:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.alfresco.repo.cache.InternalEhCacheManagerFactoryBean] for bean with name 'internalEHCacheManager' defined in class path resource [alfresco/cache-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.repo.cache.InternalEhCacheManagerFactoryBean
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(BaseApplicationContextHelper.java:67)
>       at org.alfresco.util.ApplicationContextHelper.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextHelper.java:46)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUpContext(BaseAlfrescoTestCase.java:84)
>       at org.alfresco.util.BaseAlfrescoTestCase.setUp(BaseAlfrescoTestCase.java:102)

Comment: My first guess is that you've not included all the bits of Alfresco that you need. Are you able to tell us what bits of Alfresco you depended on in your pom, and at what version?

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry all dependencies are too long for a comment... please see the edit on my post

Comment: You seem to have a mixture of Alfresco versions in there - some 4.0.d and some 3.4.e. You probably want to fix that first!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I've updated the 3.4.e sources. Please find the new dependencies in my original post.
Unfortunately the error during the test remains...
I do not understand, why I have to add "-SNAPSHOT" to the alfresco-data-model and alfresco-web-client dependencies. If I do not add SNAPSHOT the dependencies cannot be resolved by maven. The alfresco-core dependency obviously does not need any addition.

Comment: Why are you using 3.4.e? It's ancient! The maven support is currently still somewhat WIP, so you'll have more chance with a more recent one (eg something from 4.1 enterprise or 4.2 community)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why :) Whats about compatibility to older Alfresco versions, when I am changing the version to 4.1/4.2?
I'll have a try with newer Alfresco versions...

Comment: I changed the versions for all dependencies regarding to Alfresco to 4.2.c. But the application-context.xml exception still remains.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `application-context.xml` and friends live in the config directory, not the source directory. They are included in the war, but not in the default built jars. I'm not sure if there's a maven jar artifact that includes them, or it you'd need to pull in the war / reference them from a source checkout

Comment: As the project is an Alfresco module, I do not have any of these configuration files. I think the module is using the default Alfresco configuration files. For testing I do not deploy the war to any Alfresco installation. I was hoping to run the test with a local environment (jetty?).
I could copy the application-context.xml from a Alfresco installation to the src/test/config/alfresco folder, but this doesn't solve the problem. The application-xml "includes" a lot of XMLs and all of them are missing.
The problem is I have no clue what these configuration files should look like.

Comment: You need to use the actual configuration files from the version of Alfresco that you're compiling and deploying against, otherwise you won't have the right services available to run your code!

Comment: Are the configuration files included in any package (alfresco-core or something like this)? Where do I get all these needed configuration files? Sorry I'm getting more and more confused.
I can compile the package skipping the tests. The package runs on a alfresco/tomcat installation on a separate server. For testing I would appreciate to run the JUnit tests on my dev machine (Mac OSX 10.8.4, Java 1.6.0_51, Maven 3.0.3). Is there maybe any tutorial for dummies how to set up a test environment? All tuts I've found didn't work for me.

Comment: The configuration files are included in the war, or you can get them by checkout out the source tree - look in `projects/repository/config/alfresco/` and `projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/`, or the repo (but not remote api) config files are in the SDK.

Comment: it seems that i got a step forward. I searched the local maven repository for the war file you mentioned. I found an alfresco 4.0.b community war file in `repository/org/alfresco/alfresco/4.0.b/`. In the war I found application-context.xml and application-context-core.xml and I copied both files to src/test/resource/alfresco. In addition i copied the fake-context folder from war to /src/test/resource/test/alfresco/. Sadly the needed beans are not included. Please see original post for the error message. Are these the wrong xmls?

Comment: You can't just copy a couple of context files and hope for the best, you'll need all of the context xml files and their associated properties if you want to start a repo!

Comment: Please see the last two Edits in my post. I copied the complete alfresco folder into the project. But now the ServiceRegistry bean is missing. I trawled through the XMLs and found the bean. I don't know why it's not gonna be loaded. Can you please give me an advice where I get the right configuration files? I didn't get it in your last comment ...

Comment: You appear to be missing one of the dependent libraries. At this point, you might be best off just giving up on Maven, waiting a year for Alfresco to finish moving the build over + fixing things up to work with it, and just grab the jars out of the Alfresco SDK + build with ant!

Answer (score 0):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [alfresco/application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist at

make sure you have **alfresco/application-context.xml** in the classpath. Where do you put your application-context.xml? try to put it in: src/main/resources/alfresco/application-context.xml, maven will copy it to the classpath

Comment: So actually I do not have a application-context.xml, as I mentioned in my post. My problem is, that I do now know where I get a valid application-context.xml or how I can create one. When I copy an application-context.xml from any alfresco installation to src/test/resources/alfresco there are a lot new dependencies missing (alfresco-core.xml ...). So obviously it is the right place... Do I have to copy all these xmls in src/test/resources/alfresco?